# Colimits from van Kampen cocones

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, limits-and-colimits

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category with pullbacks, $\mathcal{J}$ a small category, $F : \mathcal{J} \to \mathcal{C}$ a diagram and $\kappa : F \Rightarrow \Delta X$ a cocone in $\mathcal{C}$. Let $\mathcal{D}$ be the full subcategory of $[\mathcal{J}, \mathcal{C}]/F$ on the *equifibered*, or *cartesian* natural transformations (those for which every naturality square is a pullback). Let $\mathrm{Pb} : \mathcal{C}/X \to \mathcal{D}$ be the evident functor obtained by pulling back along $\kappa$. Recall (from [1]) that $\kappa$ is a **van Kampen** cocone if $\mathrm{Pb}$ is an equivalence of categories.

If additionally $\mathcal{C}$ has all $\mathcal{J}$-colimits, then $\mathrm{Pb}$ has a left adjoint given by taking colimits "upstairs". This leads to the elementary "colimit iff pullback" characterisation of van Kampen colimits.

I am interested in the following "reverse-mathematical" question: **assuming only that $\kappa$ is a van Kampen cocone in this sense, what colimits exist in $\mathcal{C}$**?

This can be broken down into two questions: under what minimal set of assumptions can we conclude

1. that $\kappa$ is a colimiting cocone?
2. that the colimit of a $\mathcal{J}$-diagram over $F$ exists?

For 1, I've been able to come up with the following argument: *assuming that $\mathcal{C}$ has binary products with $X$*, then $\kappa$ is a colimiting cocone: we have $$\mathcal{C}(X, Y) \simeq \mathcal{C}/X(\mathrm{id}, \pi_1 : X \times Y \to X) \simeq \mathcal{D}(\mathrm{Pb}(\mathrm{id}), \mathrm{Pb}(\pi_1)) \simeq \mathcal{D}(\mathrm{id}, \pi_1 : F \times \Delta Y \Rightarrow F) \simeq [\mathcal{J},\mathcal{C}](F, \Delta Y)$$ using that $\mathrm{Pb}$ is fully faithful, and it should be easy to check that the forwards direction of the isomorphism is given by composition with $\kappa$. Can we get rid of the assumption?

For 2, [2, remark 3.2] seems to say that, assuming that $\mathcal{C}$ has pullbacks and that pushouts along monomorphisms are van Kampen in this sense, then $\mathcal{C}$ has all pushouts along monomorphisms. This doesn't make sense to me, as surely one can craft a category with all pullbacks and no pushouts, so that the second assumption holds vacuously? Can anyone figure out what that remark is actually trying to say?

Motivation: I am formalising van Kampen colimits in Agda, and I'd like to understand under what assumptions exactly the elementary characterisation is available.

---

1. [Being van Kampen is a universal property](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.4594.pdf), Tobias Heindel, Paweł Sobociński
2. Adhesive and quasiadhesive categories, Stephen Lack, Paweł Sobociński